# loop through IEnumerable and group by date and time span differences

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable object that I created from a LINQ query.

The data would look something like this:

```
Id        EventName        EventDate        EventStart      EventEnd
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1        StoryTime          4/6/2018        8:00            8:45        
2        Baking             4/6/2018        8:55            9:30
3        Cooking            4/7/2018        7:45            9:50
4        Comprehension      4/8/2018        9:05            10:10
5        WindDown           4/8/2018        10:25           10:55
6        Naptime            4/8/2018        11:00           11:30
7        Play               4/8/2018        13:50           14:20
8        Smarts             4/8/2018        14:30           16:00
9        StoryTime          4/9/2018        9:30            12:05
10       FunTime            4/10/2018       14:10           16:10
```

I need to loop through the IEnumerable and examine the data by checking the dates and times. I want to group together events that are on the same day and where the Event's EventStart time is no more than 30 minutes from the previous activities EventEnd time.

The logic is tough.  I've been trying different things, but I can't find any way of doing this.

Here is where I have gotten so far:

```
// loop through IEnumerable object created with linq query
foreach (var e in eventResults)
{
    // set current interation current date
    DateTime? currentDate = e.EventDate;

    // make sure we are only checking time span differences in the same day
    while (e.EventDate == currentDate)
    {
         int currentId = e.Id;
         DateTime? currentStartTime = e.EventStart;
         DateTime? currentEndTime = e.EventEnd; 

        // stuck -- not sure where to go with my logic  :(
    }
}
```

When it's all done, it would look something like this:

- On 4/6,  StoryTime + Baking: 8:00 - 9:30
- On 4/7,  Cooking: 7:45 - 9:50
- On 4/8,  Comprehension + WindDown + Naptime: 9:05 - 11:30
- On 4/8,  Play + Smarts: 13:50 - 16:00
- On 4/9,  StoryTime: 9:30 - 12:05
- On 4/10, FunTime: 14:10 - 16:10

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could provide some help.  Thanks!

Comment: As you say *"The logic is tough"*, so as some CS professor said... complex IT problems can be simplified by adding an additional layer of redirection. So here is your extra layer: First group by day without worrying about the times within a day. Then, within each day, create the subgroups with appropriate times. When done, flatten the group hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some linq approach with group by day and `Aggregate` to create dynamic sub-groups (lists actually) within each day:

```
var eventResults = new[]
{
    new EventItem(1, "StoryTime", new DateTime(2018, 4, 6), new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(8, 45, 0)),
    new EventItem(2, "Baking", new DateTime(2018, 4, 6), new TimeSpan(8,55, 0), new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0)),
    new EventItem(3, "Cooking", new DateTime(2018, 4, 7), new TimeSpan(7,45, 0), new TimeSpan(9, 50, 0)),
    new EventItem(4, "Comprehension", new DateTime(2018, 4, 8), new TimeSpan(9, 5, 0), new TimeSpan(10,10, 0)),
    new EventItem(5, "WindDown", new DateTime(2018, 4, 8), new TimeSpan(10,25, 0), new TimeSpan(10,55, 0)),
    new EventItem(6, "Naptime", new DateTime(2018, 4, 8), new TimeSpan(11,0, 0), new TimeSpan(11,30, 0)),
    new EventItem(7, "Play", new DateTime(2018, 4, 8), new TimeSpan(13,50,0), new TimeSpan(14,20, 0)),
    new EventItem(8, "Smarts", new DateTime(2018, 4, 8), new TimeSpan(14,30,0), new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0)),
    new EventItem(9, "StoryTime", new DateTime(2018, 4, 9), new TimeSpan(9,30, 0), new TimeSpan(12, 5, 0)),
    new EventItem(10, "FunTime", new DateTime(2018, 4, 10), new TimeSpan(14,10,0), new TimeSpan(16,10, 0)),
};
var groups = eventResults
    .GroupBy(x => x.EventDate)
    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.EventStart)
        .Aggregate(new List<List<EventItem>> { new List<EventItem>() }, (l, e) =>
        {
            if ((e.EventStart - l.Last().Select(x => x.EventEnd).DefaultIfEmpty(e.EventStart).Last()).TotalMinutes <= 30)
            {
                l.Last().Add(e);
            }
            else
            {
                l.Add(new List<EventItem> { e });
            }
            return l;
        })
        .Select(x =>
        new
        {
            Date = g.Key,
            activities = x
        }))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.activities.First().EventStart);

foreach (var item in groups)
{
    var activities = string.Join(" + ", item.activities.Select(x => x.EventName));
    Console.WriteLine($"On {item.Date}, {activities}: {item.activities.First().EventStart} - {item.activities.Last().EventEnd}");
}
```

The key point is, that the requirement of grouping entries when they are less than `X` apart is not a suitable grouping condition. So instead there needs to be some sort of iteration over the (sorted) entries within each day.

I don't specifically advocate the usage of Aggregate over a traditional loop here. It's just the way I decided to code this thing. Coding the loop would probably be more beginner friendly (easier to read).

Comment: This looks great, thank you!  At the very end, in the foreach (var item in groups), how would I get the results of the looping into an IEnumerable object instead of writing out to console?  Thanks again!

Comment: So I got it to run without errors, but it's doing something strange.  It's returning a list, but the list is missing the appended events. For example, if I'm expecting, "StoryTime + Baking", I'm only seeing StoryTime and Baking is missing.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell You can append an *Edit* section to your question, where you show your solution approach based on my answer. It's probably just a tiny adjustion but it's hard for me to understand your specific problem from this comment alone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you'd do the *entire* problem in LINQ but, if you found a way, it might be less readable so it's best, IMHO, to use a partially LINQ-based approach:

```
var flattened = new List<Event>();
for (int i = events.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    events.TimeOffset = events[i].EventStart - events[i - 1].EventEnd;
}

foreach (var grouping in events.GroupBy(g => g.EventName))
{
    var compressed = grouping.First();
    foreach (var ev in grouping)
    {
        if (ev.TimeOffset?.Minutes > 30 ?? false)
        {
            // In this case, we have flattened as far as we can
            // Add the event and start over
            flattened.Add(compressed);
            compressed = new Event
            {
                Id = ev.Id,
                EventName = ev.EventName,
                EventDate = ev.EventDate,
                EventStart = ev.EventStart,
                EventEnd = ev.EventEnd
            };
        }
        else
        {
            compressed.Name = $"{compressed.Name} + {ev.Name}";
            compressed.EventEnd = ev.EventEnd;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in this case I added a field to `Event` called `TimeOffset` but you could accomplish the same thing with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Using an extension `GroupByWhile` that groups according while a boolean is true, which is based on `ScanPair`, an implementation of APL's scan operator (like aggregate but returns intermediate results) that works a pair at a time:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    // TKey combineFn((TKey Key, T Value) PrevKeyItem, T curItem):
    // PrevKeyItem.Key = Previous Key
    // PrevKeyItem.Value = Previous Item
    // curItem = Current Item
    // returns new Key
    public static IEnumerable<(TKey Key, T Value)> ScanPair<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TKey seedKey, Func<(TKey Key, T Value), T, TKey> combineFn) {
        using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (srce.MoveNext()) {
                var prevkv = (seedKey, srce.Current);

                while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                    yield return prevkv;
                    prevkv = (combineFn(prevkv, srce.Current), srce.Current);
                }
                yield return prevkv;
            }
        }
    }

    // bool testFn(T prevItem, T curItem)
    // returns groups by sequential matching bool
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupByWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, bool> testFn) =>
        src.ScanPair(1, (kvp, cur) => testFn(kvp.Value, cur) ? kvp.Key : kvp.Key + 1)
           .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

}
```

You can easily group your `data` according to your rules:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

var grouped = data
                .OrderBy(r => r.EventDate)
                .ThenBy(r => r.EventStart)
                .GroupByWhile((p,n) => p.EventDate.Date == n.EventDate.Date && n.EventStart-p.EventEnd < ts);
```

If you need an `IEnumerable<List<EventResult>>` then you can add

```
.Select(rg => rg.ToList())
```

to the end, assuming your original `data` is of type `IEnumerable<EventResult>`.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to import any external libraries to use this extension?  I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I actually just figured out that the class should outside the main class.  So I have implemented the extension method, but "grouped" is of type IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, EventResult>>.  How would I convert that to a List of <EventResult> ?  Thanks!

Comment: So I figured out how to convert it back to a List, but it's missing the grouping (duh on my part) so I'm back to where I started...

Comment: I added code to make the result `IEnumerable<List<EventResult>>`.

Comment: Thanks.  But it's still complaining about the grouping when I run it.  It's expects this: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[EventManager.Models.EventResult], but is getting this type: 'System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,EventManager.Models.EventResult]

Comment: Are you using `eventResults` in place of `data`? What is the type of `eventResults`? Also, `IEnumerable<EventResult>` implies no grouping - so what is the point of the grouping in that case? Ordering? Then you need to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`... but I'm pretty sure you just end of with the original data sorted and that's a much easier thing to do.